# Can't see iOS App Icon in P3 Color on latest iOS devices that support it

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, retina-display, color-profile

The attached image has been saved via Sketch (also tried Figma) in the P3 colourspace, 16 bit per channel. However when I include this in Xcode assets (as a P3 gamut app icon) the P3 text (which is [255,0,0] in P3 colorspace) isn't visible. I've tried on physical iPhone 13 and 15 Pro devices - still not visible. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

[image]